# Speed up integer reading from file in C++

Tags: c++, performance, parsing, fstream

I'm reading a file, line by line, and extracting integers from it. Some noteworthy points:

- the input file is not in binary;
- I cannot load up the whole file in memory;
- file format (only integers, separated by some delimiter):

  ```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 ...
  y1 y2 y3 ...
  z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 ...
  ...
  ```

*Just to add context*, I'm reading the integers, and counting them, using an `std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsinged int>`.

Simply looping through lines, and allocating useless stringstreams, like this:

```
std::fstream infile(<inpath>, std::ios::in);
while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
}
```

gives me ~2.7s for a 700MB file.

Parsing each line:

```
unsigned int item;
std::fstream infile(<inpath>, std::ios::in);
while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while (ss >> item);
}
```

Gives me ~17.8s for the same file.

If I change the operator to a `std::getline` + `atoi`:

```
unsigned int item;
std::fstream infile(<inpath>, std::ios::in);
while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while (std::getline(ss, token, ' ')) item = atoi(token.c_str());
}
```

It gives ~14.6s.

Is there anything faster than these approaches? I don't think it's necessary to speed up the file reading, just the parsing itself -- both wouldn't make no harm, though (:

Comment: If you're pulling apart 700MB of text into lines and not using the file or the line var afterward, and it is all happening in 2.7 seconds, I would consider you peek at your asm, because it sounds like the line-reader is optimized out. Likewise, change the `unsigned item` to `volatile unsigned item` to ensure the compiler doesn't hork your algorithm tests.

Comment: Is the timing given for the *exact* code shown. I.e., you're not doing something else like pushing it into a data structure or whatever, right?

Comment: Why don't you profile your code?

Comment: 'the input file is not in binary' - I'm pretty sure it is.

Comment: @metal The timings are just for the code I posted, although I must perform insertions in an `std::unordered_map` later.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I guess I wouldn't have timings if I wasn't profiling the code -- not sure if this is what it's meant as profiling, though.

Comment: Something like this: http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/

Comment: @MartinJames Yep, just choose the wrong words; the input is text, binary ascii, not integers occupying 4 bytes.

Comment: @Rubens: Profiling means knowing how much time is taken for each operation. Then you know what to optimize. For instance, see [`perf tools`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org). What you do is not called a profiling.

Comment: @WhozCraig the reading was optimized, actually; I've been compiling the code with `-O3`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This program

```
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{
    int num;
    while (std::cin >> num) ;
}
```

needs about 17 seconds to read a file. This code

```
#include <iostream>   
int main()
{
    int lc = 0;
    int item = 0;
    char buf[2048];
    do
    {
        std::cin.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
        int k = std::cin.gcount();
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        {
            switch (buf[i])
            {
                case '\r':
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    item = 0; lc++;
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    item = 0;
                    break;
                case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3':
                case '4': case '5': case '6': case '7':
                case '8': case '9':
                    item = 10*item + buf[i] - '0';
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cerr << "Bad format\n";
            }    
        }
    } while (std::cin);
}
```

needs 1.25 seconds for the same file. Make what you want of it...

Comment: Let me check if are they real the words you say (:

Comment: infile -> 713M; >>> Time: 6.92311s; >>> Time: 6.92076s; >>> Time: 6.92203s. I must say I'm very disappointed with you; you promised me 1.25 seconds \= LOL Thank you, very much, that's the very best I've got so far (:

Comment: I used a smaller file to reduce wait time, I have a slow machine.

Comment: No execuses; [You lose! Good day sir!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKG07305CBs) haha I'm really really thankful for this snippet! (:

Comment: Be warned that it does not appear to handle +/- signs and does not error check for invalid values, which may be acceptable for your application.

Comment: @n.m. Compiled with `-O3`: >>> Time: 1.27087s; >>> Time: 1.29635s; >>> Time: 1.31416s. It sort of looks fine now ^^

Comment: @metal Thanks for pointing it out; yes, it is valid to my application, and, yes, I should've pointed it out in my question.

Comment: @metal: it is not very hard to add +/- and error checks, in fact I have done so. These additions have minimal effect on performance. But then the code won't fit in a code section without a scrollbar.

Comment: @n.m.: I was just noting the posted code is not a universal solvent. If you know there are no signs or errors in your data file, the posted code should work well. For large files, reading in bigger chunks may speed it up further.

Answer (score 2):

Streams are slow. If you really want to do stuff fast load the entire file into memory, and parse it in memory. If you really can't load it all into memory, load it in chunks, making those chunks as large as possible, and parse the chunks in memory.

When parsing in memory, replace the spaces and line endings with nulls so you can use `atoi` to convert to integer as you go.

Oh, and you'll get problems with the end of chunks because you don't know whether the chunk end cuts off a number or not. To solve this easily stop a small distance (16 byte should do) before the chunk end and copy this tail to the start before loading the next chunk after it.

Comment: NB: if you know the range of your numbers it would be considerably faster to count them using an array or vector rather than a map for constant time access instead of log(n).

Comment: I've tried using `fgets` + `sscanf`, to read the integers, and things just got worse. I'm betting on the `sscanf` function, but I'm not sure of what to do instead. Would the replacement of whitespaces with `NULL` be faster? And how would I do the iteration with `atoi`? Does it return the number of chars used as an integer?

Comment: The value `atoi` would return could be used to determine how many chars it used, but I think this would slow things down

Comment: @JasonSperske I thought of this to do the iteration through the buffer. Other than this, I don't know how to iterate -- not in a `char` array.

Comment: Jack is suggesting using std::fread or similar to read in big chunks (instead of fgets to get a line), then parsing the line endings yourself in memory. That may be considerably faster.

Comment: @metal Yep, I got that; I'm just not sure of how to iterate in the buffer if not by considering the number of characters read by `atoi`.

Comment: You know how many character you move forward by, because you do it behind you. You find the end of the integer, set that character to null, and then pass the first character of the integer to `atoi`. The atoi always happens behind your current read point.

Comment: But, in any case, n.m's approach will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried input iterators?

It skips the creation of the strings:

```
std::istream_iterator<int> begin(infile);
std::istream_iterator<int> end;
int item = 0;
while(begin != end)
    item = *begin++;
```

Comment: It's yet taking quite as long as the initial `>>` approach; +1 thanks for your attention, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you skip the stream and the line buffers and read from the file stream directly?

```
template<class T, class CharT, class CharTraits>
std::vector<T> read(std::basic_istream<CharT, CharTraits> &in) {
    std::vector<T> ret;
    while(in.good()) {
        T x;
        in >> x;
        if(in.good()) ret.push_back(x);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

http://ideone.com/FNJKFa

Comment: I guess this approach would take quite the same time as @utnapistim and my example with the `>>`, as it also uses the `>>` operator. Thanks for your attention, though!

Answer (score 1):

Following up Jack Aidley's answer (can't put code in the comments), here's some pseudo-code:

```
vector<char> buff( chunk_size );
roffset = 0;
char* chunk = &buff[0];
while( not done with file )
{
    fread( chunk + roffset, ... ); // Read a sizable chunk into memory, filling in after roffset
    roffset = find_last_eol(chunk); // find where the last full line ends
    parse_in_mem( chunk, chunk_size - roffset ); // process up to the last full line
    move_unprocessed_to_front( chunk, roffset ); // don't re-read what's already in mem
}
```

Comment: Which comes to be fast, as proved by @n.m's implementation. Thanks!